# Parse Many-To-Many Exclude

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've got a basic many to many relationship in Parse between a User and Photo. I'm using a joining class called PhotoDecision (as they can like or dislike the photo) that connects the two:

```
User -----> PhotoDecision <----- Photo
```

It's super easy to get all the photos that a user has made a decision on:

```
(on PhotoDecision class)
public func whereKey(key: String, equalTo object: AnyObject) -> Self
```

But how would we get the photo they haven't yet decided on?

I know we can use:

```
(on PhotoDecision class)
public func whereKey(key: String, notContainedIn array: [AnyObject]) -> Self
```

But this isn't very scalable. What if they have liked 500 photos? I can't send them all as an exclusion.

Comment: So, `PhotoDescision` has a pointer to the Photo object?  Create a query, query2 on `PhotoDecision` with user=currentUser and then create a query on Photo that uses `whereKey("objectID",doesNotMatchKey:"photo",inQuery:query2)`

Comment: Yeah, just found that function after I wrote the question, but still no love. It seems to be completely ignoring the results of the subquery (which i've verified is working). After searching for related problems I came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519862/doesnotmatchkeyinquery-return-records-that-match-key-in-parse-sdk-for-ios, but i'm not a fan of the answers...

Comment: Those answers are probably right - it is the better approach. Parse isn't a relational database

Comment: What happens when there is never 1000 decisions for a user? 2000? Having an array of that many records (even if they are just IDs) doesn't seem very scalable. Maybe NoSQL is good for that type of thing, it just feels wrong to me.

Comment: The other approach is an array on the photo that contains the users that have made a decision on the photo - you need to decide whether it is more likely that lots of users will make decisions on a single photo or a user will make decisions on lots of photos

Comment: Then when there are over 2k users that have made a decision on thousands of photos we run into the same problem. There must be a way to solve this problem in a scalable fashion. If I were to go down that route, the bottle neck would be fetching/submitting those thousands of ID's and processing them locally. Id be happy to keep them on the server if there was a way to reference them in a query without fetching them locally.

Comment: It may just be that Parse isn't the right backend for your application.

Comment: Definitely not in the long term, but i'm using it for a prototype/MVP just to get something off the ground. It'll need something more scalable long term. I'm really hoping we can get something working as I can't afford the time to build a proper back end with the time frame we have.

Comment: Azure mobile services can probably provide what you need, but cost more.

Comment: Have a look at how Parse themselves solve the issue of likes in the Anypic tutorial app